# jQuery Autocomplete UI plugin with multiple field with same id

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I try to use jQUery-UI autocomplete plugin with a list of inputs that have the same id.

The list is like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cod[]" id="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" id="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" id="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" id="cod"/>
```

My script.js function look like this:

```
$("#cod_prod").autocomplete({
source:getCods
});
```

Where getCods is a function that load data from a DB with $.ajax method of jQuery.

This work, i try it in other input ... but when i try with this list of multiple input field the plugin only work with the first field.

Any idea of how can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: id should be unique for each dom element. you can use class instead

Comment: Based on your question alone, #cod_prod does not exist in the DOM. Please explain to which element cod_prod refers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's need to be unique. Use a `class`. 
Since your ID's are not unique, that is why it only works with the first instance of it in the DOM.

```
<input type="text" name="cod[]" class="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" class="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" class="cod"/>
<input type="text" name="cod[]" class="cod"/>


$(".cod").autocomplete({
   source:getCods
});
```